# xml file to php table

Tags: php, xml

I create simple xml file , and try tu print result in php table but with some reason that dont work i paste my xml and php code maybe some body can help;

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<root>
    <Ciezarowe>
        <BOVA>
            <Futura_FHD10>
                <ID>AU-1080</ID>
                <SY>09.2001</SY>
                <EY>nie okteslil idota</EY>
                <WVA>29087 29042</WVA>
                <ID2>AU-1080</ID2>
                <WVA2>29087 29042</WVA2>
            </Futura_FHD10>
        </BOVA>
    </Ciezarowe>
```

And PHP code:

```
<?php
    $get = file_get_contents('aaa.xml');
    $arr = simplexml_load_string($get);
    $data = $arr -> root ;
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Przod</th>
        <th>Rok Produkcji</th>
        <th>Koniec Produkcji</th>
        <th>WVA</th>
        <th>Tyl</th>
        <th>WVA2</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach($data as $row) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->ID ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->SY ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->EY ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->WVA ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->ID2 ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->WVA2 ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: 'that don't work' is somewhat vague. what is happening? do you get any error?

Comment: I dont get any error only tabel with name's (th) and empty td when should be xml text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You xml is not valid because root tag is not closed.

If you can't change code, generating xml, just add close tag to string. And your code will work

```
$arr = simplexml_load_string($get . '</root>');
```

And change this line

```
$data = $arr->Ciezarowe->BOVA->Futura_FHD10;
```

Comment: i got a lot o errors 

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 35: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in C:\WebServ\httpd-users\php\katalog4.php on line 105

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): </root></root> in C:\WebServ\httpd-users\php\katalog4.php on line 105

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\WebServ\httpd-users\php\katalog4.php on line 105

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\WebServ\httpd-users\php\katalog4.php on line 118

Comment: Ye thats work for me too . But i  dont have problem to display/print first code tabel  i Got problem to display/print  text from xml to second code table